# Book: main character is a half-blood working as a mage's servant, eventually becomes the leader of a werewolf pack

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf, wizards, demons

All I can remember is, the protagonist is a half-demon or devil who works as a servant for a mage. The mage is a sword master that graduated from an academy where everyone receives a scar on their chin at the graduation ceremonial fight, but he never got his, as he was too skilled to get hit.

And later on the half-blood guy becomes leader of a pack of werewolves and falls in love with this gypsy girl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be thinking of [*Prince of Wolves*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8510013-prince-of-wolves) by Dave Gross.  It is a Pathfinder role-playing tie-in novel.

Summary from publisher:

> For elven Pathfinder Varian Jeggare and his devil-blooded assistant Radovan, things are rarely as they seem. Yet not even the notorious crime-solving duo is prepared for what they find when a search for a missing Pathfinder takes them into the mist-shrouded mountains of gothic Ustalav. Beset on all sides by noble intrigue, mysterious locals, and the deadly creatures of the night, Varian and Radovan must use both sword and spell to track the strange rumors to their source and uncover a secret of unimaginable proportions. But it'll take more than merely solving the mystery to finish this job, for a shadowy figure has taken note of the pair's investigations, and is set on making sure neither man gets out of Ustalav alive...

[image: Prince of Wolves cover]

I read it a while ago and do recall that the two get separated.  Radovan definitely gets involved with a "gypsy"/werewolf group.  Don't recall the bit about the scar or academy for Varian.  Good news is, if this is it, there are a couple sequels.

Comment: This is it thank you so much I've been looking for this for a couple of months now. Very much appreciated.